# Why JVM doesn't optimize simple callback (in Scala)?

Tags: scala, optimization, jvm, benchmarking

I'm creating Scala method to add elements into a `ArrayBuffer`. I'm thinking about 2 approaches:

- `def addToArrayBuffer(b: ArrayBuffer[Int])`
- `def addToArrayBuffer(cb: Int => Unit)`

The first approach is a method which gets collection and adds elements into it. The second approach is a method which gets callback `cb` and calls this callback for every element I want to add into collection.

The second approach is more flexible because I can transform/filter elements before adding them into collection.

Unfortunately the second approach is slower (72 ops/s vs 57 ops/s):

```
Benchmark                                        Mode  Cnt   Score    Error  Units
TestBenchmark.addToArrayBufferDirectly          thrpt    9  72.808 ? 13.394  ops/s
TestBenchmark.addToArrayBufferViaCallback       thrpt    9  57.786 ?  3.532  ops/s
```

My question is why is JVM unable to optimize callback and achieve the same speed as direct adding into collection? And how can I improve speed?

I'm using `java` version `1.8.0_162` on Mac. Here is the source of benchmark:

```scala
package bench

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.{Benchmark, Fork, Measurement, Scope, State, Warmup}
import org.openjdk.jmh.infra.Blackhole

import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

@State(Scope.Thread)
@Warmup(iterations = 5)
@Measurement(iterations = 3)
@Fork(3)
class TestBenchmark {

  val size = 1000000

  @Benchmark
  def addToArrayBufferDirectly(blackhole: Blackhole) = {
    def addToArrayBuffer(b: ArrayBuffer[Int]) = {
      var i = 0
      while (i < size) {
        b.append(i)
        i += 1
      }
    }

    val ab = new ArrayBuffer[Int](size)
    addToArrayBuffer(ab)
    blackhole.consume(ab)
  }

  @Benchmark
  def addToArrayBufferViaCallback(blackhole: Blackhole) = {
    def addToArrayBuffer(cb: Int => Unit) = {
      var i = 0
      while (i < size) {
        cb(i)
        i += 1
      }
    }

    val ab = new ArrayBuffer[Int](size)
    addToArrayBuffer(i => ab.append(i))
    blackhole.consume(ab)
  }
}
```

Comment: The callback version is instantiating a function object, and the JVM's not going to optimize that away. It looks like the difference is within the margin of error, anyway—I don't think there's much reason to worry about this.

Comment: And can I do something to force Scala compiler to inline callback?

Comment: You could write a macro, but that's almost definitely a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be optimized by Scala compiler by using flags

```scala
scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-opt-inline-from:bench.**",
  "-opt:l:inline"
)
```

No changes in code are necessary. More about Scala inlining: https://www.lightbend.com/blog/scala-inliner-optimizer